# Does anyone know if ziplib has the ability to validate a zip library without actually extracting all the files

Tags: c++, zip, crc32

I'm looking to replace the zip library that I am using in a small utility with something a bit better.

One of the deficiencies in the library I am currently using is that it doesn't appear to validate zip file very well - I can corrupt the file by changing random characters and the library doesn't notice.

I am looking for a C++ zip library that has a function to validate the zip file without extracting all the files in the library.

Someone recommended ziplib to me, but I don't see anything in there about checking the integrity of a zip library.

Does anyone know if ziplib has this capability? Or have a better recommendation?

Comment: Unfortunately tool recommendations are off-topic here. These tend to be highly subjective and situational, so it's hard to answer in objective technical terms. Remember, if you can extract all the data without error, that's a form of verification, and you don't have to extract to disk.

Comment: What kind of verification are you looking for? If you want to know that all of the files could be extracted without errors, then you'll just want to iterate the files and iterate the whole stream for each file without copying the output anywhere, and ZipLib can do that just fine. If you only want to know that you can start decrypting each file, without verifying that they're entirely decryptable, you can just iterate the files and discard the streams without reading them. If you only want to know that the directory is valid, you can just iterate the files and not even create the streams. Etc.

Comment: ZIP is a sequential format. You have to traverse all the data somehow, to find out what the CRC should be for each entry, and check it against the header. But you don't have to write anything to the disk while doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libraries like [libzip](https://libzip.org/) and [libarchive](https://www.libarchive.org/) allow you to read archive entries a chunk at a time. You can simply read the entire archive to verify it, repeatedly overwriting the same buffer in memory with the decompressed data and thereby discarding it.